# What does "Trailing Stop buy Order" on Bitstamp mean?

Tags: trading, currencies, bitstamp

a Trailing Stop limit Order is clear in my mind.
You want to sell your stock when the price starts to fall after reaching a max;
or you want to buy a stock after the price starts to rise after a minimum.
So far so good.

Bitstamp however only has the trailing options for stop loss orders
(see pic).
[image: Stop loss orders on bitstamp]

This does not make sense in my mind: *"I would want to wait for a minimum price and than sell when it starts to grow again?"* Non sense. The same non sense applies for stop buy trailing orders.

In the picture bellow i plot 4 graphs with MY UNDERSTANDING of these options.
[image: MY UNDERSTANDING of these options]

Please help me understand what Bitstamp means with that.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You might have been confused about what a "Trailing Stop Loss" really is. (Or I do missunderstood your question.)

The answer can be found on Bitstamp's website: https://www.bitstamp.net/article/stop-orders-and-trailing-stop-orders/

> What is Trailing Stop Order and how to use it?
>
> The trailing stop is more flexible than a fixed stop loss, since it
>   automatically tracks the bitcoin’s price direction and does not have
>   to be manually reset like the fixed stop loss.
>
> For example: Market price of bitcoin is $480 and you placed a Stop
>   Sell Order at $450, which is in our case $30 below the current market
>   price. Suppose price of bitcoins suddenly increases to $550. You are
>   now in chance of “locking in” even bigger profit by manually
>   repositioning your Stop Sell Order to higher price.
>
> Repositioning your Stop Order can be done automatically for you by
>   enabling “Trailing Stop” function. In our case Trailing Stop Order
>   will automatically reposition active Stop Order if price of bitcoin
>   increases while maintaining spread of $30 between the bitcoins spot
>   price and Stop Order.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! A good answer. @user152037 when an answer resolves your question, please remember to mark it as accepted so that the question does not remain "unanswered".